# Removing file extentions windows 8

Tags: git, windows-8

I want to have a file with no extension in windows 8. The purpose of this file is to have my ignore list for git (.gitignore) file.

Comment: Simply how to save a file without extension?

Comment: Just to clarify, a `.gitignore` file as an extension (the part after the '.'). It is a file with an extension, but no name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this sir

```sh
echo > .gitignore
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've got it installed anyway, I find WinSCP a good quick alternative to Windows Explorer for renaming a local file to a filename without an extension.